# Shopify App hosted on fly.io oAuth/Auth callbacks failing

Tags: authentication, oauth, shopify, shopify-app, fly

Currently I am trying to deploy my Shopify Custom App to Fly.io. Installing this app is succeeding on my development store but I get an error right after with the oAuth callback with status code 400. This is the URL it shows upon installing:

```
https://appname.fly.dev/api/auth/callback?code=71bfdaadd63b87eb72d9d3dc516ea1ea&hmac=1efd4ff63ebca8f28c733f464ded354ba2f0995aeb1910114e0139eaefd4cce3&host=YWRtaW4uc2hvcGlmeS5jb20vc3RvcmUvc2hvb3B5bG9vcHkx&shop=shoopyloopy1.myshopify.com&state=920113322594675&timestamp=1676563785
```

With text in body: `Invalid OAuth callback.`

The app works with all the callbacks working with a ngrok tunnel during development. Just not when deployed to fly.io. The apps frontend also works after deployment to fly.io, but all the api and auth callbacks fail to work. I get the following response on those API calls:

On performing API calls on the /api/ route I get the following error in the return of the api call:

`Failed to parse session token 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvc2hvb3B5bG9vcHkxLm15c2hvcGlmeS5jb21cL2FkbWluIiwiZGVzdCI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC9zaG9vcHlsb29weTEubXlzaG9waWZ5LmNvbSIsImF1ZCI6IjU4YTAzZjkwZTk4Yjc5NGRlZmE5NDZlMWZiNmVlMzRiIiwic3ViIjoiNzQ3NzAxNTM2NjEiLCJleHAiOjE2NzY1NjQyMjYsIm5iZiI6MTY3NjU2NDE2NiwiaWF0IjoxNjc2NTY0MTY2LCJqdGkiOiI0OTcyNDEwOC0zNWQ2LTRjODEtOWJkNS0wZWRkMWM4MWIxMDYiLCJzaWQiOiIxOGZmZjg5NTMyZGRiODdiOWQ3OTBhYmY1M2EwOTZiMDNkNmE4ZWU1ZTA0ZmRjZmFmOWUxOWM2OGQxZGFjN2Q2In0.XeuA5W95YjjVLZYOvmRJ9a90xpPNEukhNQ1_z4Kw_xA': signature verification failed`

My fly.toml file:

```
app = "appname"
kill_signal = "SIGINT"
kill_timeout = 5
processes = []

[env]
  PORT = "8081"
  HOST = "https://appname.fly.dev"
  SHOPIFY_API_KEY = "58a03f90e98b794defa946e1fb6ee34b"
  SCOPES = "write_products,read_script_tags,write_script_tags"

[experimental]
  auto_rollback = true

[[services]]
  http_checks = []
  internal_port = 8081
  processes = ["app"]
  protocol = "tcp"
  script_checks = []
  [services.concurrency]
    hard_limit = 25
    soft_limit = 20
    type = "connections"

  [[services.ports]]
    force_https = true
    handlers = ["http"]
    port = 80

  [[services.ports]]
    handlers = ["tls", "http"]
    port = 443

  [[services.tcp_checks]]
    grace_period = "1s"
    interval = "15s"
    restart_limit = 0
    timeout = "2s"
```

My index.js file starting up express:

```
// @ts-check
import { join } from "path";
import { readFileSync } from "fs";
import express from "express";
import serveStatic from "serve-static";

import shopify from "./shopify.js";
import productCreator from "./product-creator.js";
import GDPRWebhookHandlers from "./gdpr.js";
import {addScriptTag, deleteScriptTag, getProductInfo, getProductsFromIds, getScriptTags} from "./graph-functions.js";

const PORT = parseInt(process.env.BACKEND_PORT || process.env.PORT, 10);

const STATIC_PATH =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? `${process.cwd()}/frontend/dist`
    : `${process.cwd()}/frontend/`;

const app = express();

// Set up Shopify authentication and webhook handling
app.get(shopify.config.auth.path, shopify.auth.begin());
app.get(
  shopify.config.auth.callbackPath,
  shopify.auth.callback(),
  shopify.redirectToShopifyOrAppRoot()
);
app.post(
  shopify.config.webhooks.path,
  shopify.processWebhooks({ webhookHandlers: GDPRWebhookHandlers })
);

// All endpoints after this point will require an active session
app.use("/api/*", shopify.validateAuthenticatedSession());

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/api/products/count", async (_req, res) => {
  const countData = await shopify.api.rest.Product.count({
    session: res.locals.shopify.session,
  });
  res.status(200).send(countData);
});

app.get("/api/get-product", async (_req, res) => {
  const products = await getProductInfo(res.locals.shopify.session, _req.query.id);
  res.status(200).send(products);
});

app.get("/api/get-products", async (_req, res) => {
  const products = await getProductsFromIds(res.locals.shopify.session,_req.query.ids);
  res.status(200).send(products);
});

app.get("/api/add-script", async (_req, res) => {
  const data = await addScriptTag(res.locals.shopify.session,_req.query.src);
  console.log(_req.query.ids);
  res.status(200).send(data);
});

app.get("/api/get-scripts", async (_req, res) => {
  const data = await getScriptTags(res.locals.shopify.session);
  res.status(200).send(data?.body?.data ? data?.body?.data : data);
});

app.get("/api/delete-script", async (_req, res) => {
  const data = await deleteScriptTag(res.locals.shopify.session,_req.query.id);
  res.status(200).send(data);
});

app.get("/api/products/create", async (_req, res) => {
  let status = 200;
  let error = null;

  try {
    await productCreator(res.locals.shopify.session);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Failed to process products/create: ${e.message}`);
    status = 500;
    error = e.message;
  }
  res.status(status).send({ success: status === 200, error });
});

app.use(serveStatic(STATIC_PATH, { index: false }));

app.use("/*", shopify.ensureInstalledOnShop(), async (_req, res, _next) => {
  return res
    .status(200)
    .set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    .send(readFileSync(join(STATIC_PATH, "index.html")));
});

app.listen(PORT);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I followed the official documentation: [Shopify Official Docs](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/deployment/web#deploy)

The Dockerfile has the same port 8081 as assigned to in the fly.toml file.

Edit (Added shopify app implementation with Database):

```
import { LATEST_API_VERSION } from "@shopify/shopify-api";
import { shopifyApp } from "@shopify/shopify-app-express";
import { SQLiteSessionStorage } from "@shopify/shopify-app-session-storage-sqlite";
import { restResources } from "@shopify/shopify-api/rest/admin/2023-01";

const DB_PATH = `${process.cwd()}/database.sqlite`;

const shopify = shopifyApp({
  api: {
    apiVersion: LATEST_API_VERSION,
    restResources,
    billing: undefined, // or replace with billingConfig above to enable example billing
  },
  auth: {
    path: "/api/auth",
    callbackPath: "/api/auth/callback",
  },
  webhooks: {
    path: "/api/webhooks",
  },
  // This should be replaced with your preferred storage strategy
  sessionStorage: new SQLiteSessionStorage(DB_PATH),
});

export default shopify;
```

Comment: What store are you using for the session? Sqlite?

Comment: @FabioFilippi Yes I am

Comment: @FabioFilippi see the edit for the implementation

Comment: I'm not expert of fly.io (which I discourage you to use in production) but are you sure the sqlite is working in their environment?

Comment: @FabioFilippi why do you discourage usage of fly.io in production? It seems more cost friendly and doesn't sleep in comparison with Heroku. According to the readme docs sqlite should be fine in production.

Comment: @FabioFilippi so, why you discourage use fly.io in production?

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the table but if you restart you shopify app server (e.g. if you run it locally and periodically kill the process and restart it) then uninstall the app, the uninstall webhook on the shopify app never gets run and all subsequent requests use an invalid API key because the shopify app thinks it never got uninstalled.

You may be able to "re-register" the app with a new API keys by visiting a backend shopify app page (like the generate product one in the default remix app), after that you should be fine & next time uninstall the application when the shopify app server is still running.
If it's a remote server issue like fly.io I'd suggest uninstalling and reinstalling the app.

Additionally another thing to note that caught me is that the webhooks you can trigger in the backend of shopify store are not able to trigger a shopify app webhook... instead you'll just need to perform whatever action it would normally need.

[The answer on a github issue](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-remix/issues/396#issuecomment-1828586268)

So unintuitive, but that's how it works currently.